# ASP .NET Timeout implementation with Display Timeout error message

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, session-timeout

I want to implement a timeout function on my ASP .net web application. So that the user will be redirected to Timeout message after 60 min.
I used the following in the webconfig

```
<sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
```

I could not find any usfull example online for this task. 
I wonder if there is anyway to implement this on client side with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: did you try timer class ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, I need to do it in ASP .Net

Comment: What kind of ASP.NET - ASP.NET Core, ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Form?

Comment: It is ASP .NET Web Forms

Comment: I recommend storing the time on each request and if the difference between the current time and stored time is > 60, then redirect.

Comment: also you can use session time out

Comment: At the web-config I've added the following for testing                
<sessionState timeout="1" mode="InProc"> </sessionState>                                       Then added the following code in the forms that I need them to timeout          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         Session.Timeout = 1;                                                                                 But it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by implementing a jQuery function that execute in clinet side, and redirect the user to time out page.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        var timeInSeconds = 30
        var timeoutTimer = timeInSeconds * 1000;
        var timeoutToRefresh = window.setTimeout(timeoutfunction, timeoutTimer)


        var isPostBack = ("true" === "<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>");

        if (!isPostBack) {
            $('#cost').hide();
            $('#imgCost').attr("src", "../../Design/Images/iconPlus.png");
        } else {
            $('#imgCost').attr("src", "../../Design/Images/minus_icon.png");
        }
    });

    var timeoutfunction = function () {
        window.location.replace('/CustomErrorPage.aspx')
    };
```